# axios response console.log returns eroor

Tags: vue.js

I want to `console.log(response)` json placeholder but it gives me error that says **"Unexpected console statement"**

Here's the code:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'app',
  created(){
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => {console.log(response)})
  }
}
```

Comment: That's from your es-lint settings, because you have `no-console` enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["unexpected console statement no-console"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409975/unexpected-console-statement-no-console)

Comment: @Terry How can I enable it ?

Comment: Update your eslint config.

Answer (score 0):

Create file `.eslintrc` in root of vue project and restart your serve.

.eslintrc

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential"
  ]
}
```